# Return value of a function with a non-default type

Tags: c, function, return-value, return-type

I have a function:

```
*Foo* create_foo();
```

where Foo is a struct with many fields:

```
typedef struct foo {
    int progr_num;
    char* size;
    char* account;
    int matric_num;
    int codex_grp;
    char* note;
} Foo;
```

What is the exactly return value of this function when I call it??

the function:

```
Foo create_foo() {
    Foo x;
    ...
    ...
    return x
}
```

I know that the return type is Foo, but if I invoke the function and want to test the return value, which is the correct value?? (for example if a funcion is an *int* type, the return is 0 or -1).

When I call the function what is the return correct value??

for example:

```
int main() {
    Foo foo_check;
    foo_check = create_foo();
    if(!foo_check)
    return ... **???**
}
```

Comment: Well, according to your explanation the function returns a struct. You need to explain what exactly you mean by "testing" that return value (i.e. the struct).

Comment: What do you mean "(for example if a function is an int type, the return is 0 or -1)" ? I think you're confused about returns types. In `int create_int();` the returned int is any positive or negative or zero integer within a large range.

Comment: @Kyrol: `Foo create_foo();` isn't a function.  Its a function definition.  The value of your return is defined within the function.  Maybe I'm not understanding your question...

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I'm not confused. I know it, just look now I edit the question in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than passing the (large) struct back and forth on the stack, pass a pointer and use the stack for a status indicator.

```
struct foo { /* ... whatever ... */ };
int fxfoo(struct foo *pfoo) { /* ... whatever ... */ return ALLOK?0:1; }
int main(void) {
    struct foo objfoo;
    if (fxfoo(&objfoo)) /* error */;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand... but I don't understand the -1 to my question. Ok is a stupid question, but I just wanted to understand!

thanks for your answer however!

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. I also have the opinion downvoting should be explained :)

Comment: Exactly... Ok, I understand the error. Instead of do a function with struct type, I have to do a function with int type and pass the pointer of the struct as a parameter. Right? ;)

Comment: Right. That's the usual way to do it.

Comment: If a function returns a `Foo`, it returns a `Foo`, simple as that. It never returns any extra information. It appears that you want to 'return' two pieces of information. You want to return the success or otherwise of the function, and if it was successful, you want to access a `Foo` with the answer. That is what @pmg has done.

Answer (score 0):

The return value is a full instance of the structure `Foo`. If you would like to check its value, you would have to assign it to something and then check field by field.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct A{
int x;
char c;
}

Foo create_foo(){
struct A a;
a.x = 5;
a.c = 'd';

return a; // <-- This will be your return value.
}
```

Comment: This is ok, but now I edit better the question. I think I explain worst at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You use the return value the same way you would use any return value...

```
Foo x = create_foo();
if(x.field == y) {...};
```